# Do I "feel gratified" or am I just "gratified"?

Tags: word-usage

Is one more correct than the other? "am feeling gratified" vs. "am gratified"

Is "feeling" redundant or otherwise unnecessary...?

Comment: It's pretty much redundant. It just gives a couple more syllables to swell the perceived sincerity of the formal response; lots of people appear to think that the longer they talk, the more sincere they sound.

Comment: It depends on how you feel.

Comment: It depends on whether you want that product  to be part of the "greatness". [joke]

Answer (score 1):

If you are gratified then you have received what you asked for or wanted.

That doesn't imply that you *feel* gratified, that is, that you feel that you got what you wanted.

---

> **Adjective:** gratified -- 'gra-ti,fId
>
> 1. Having received what was desired
>
>    "Their screams of fear need to be gratified with reassurance"
>
> **Verb:** gratify -- 'gra-ti,fI
>
> 1. Make happy or satisfied
>
>    - satisfy
> 2. Yield (to); give satisfaction to
>
>    - pander, indulge

Answer (score 0):

If you are "feeling gratified" then you are **grateful**.

> 1 Feeling or showing an appreciation for something done or received.
>   ‘I'm grateful to you for all your help’ ‘she gave him a grateful
>   smile’
>
> 1.1 archaic Received or experienced with gratitude; welcome. ‘the grateful shade’
>   [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/grateful)

So you are either *grateful* or *gratified*.

See also [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=icnKIlILT4oC&pg=PA137&lpg=PA137&dq=oed+%2B+gratified&source=bl&ots=9ZzaiWnACn&sig=J_ZTq_kpHsn1nGAmoUt7cRaxbRg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiYg4bEv6XVAhVDGD4KHb9oADAQ6AEISDAG).

Comment: I stand by my answer. "But the only way never to do the wrong thing is never to do anything." Jim Butcher, White Night

Comment: Ingrates. Have a gratuitous +1, because I'm trying to ingratiate myself.

Comment: @PhilSweet Done.  :-)